# Log4j : how to skip loading of a log4j Custom Appender during server startup

Tags: log4j

I use the following log4j.xml file ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE">
      <param value="${logfile}" name="File" />
      <param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex" />
      <param value="200MB" name="MaxFileSize" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender class="com.ubsc.at.properties.Log4JCustomAppender" name="CUSTAPPEN">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%m" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
      </appender>

   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC">
     <param name="Blocking" value="false"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="512"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CUSTAPPEN" />
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="${logLevel}" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I am getting problem shown below during the time jetty server is started .

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ubsc.at.properties.Log4JCustomAppender
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
```

I guess this is because log4j.xml is loaded much prior than my custom Appender class ??

Is there anyway i can apply Class Level filtering so that i can skip loadin this class during server start up .

Please suggest , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't avoid this with a file named `log4j.xml`. Since this is the default name for log4j config files, there's probably other Log4J installation than yours that is trying to initialize.

Here's some solutions :

1. If you're using Spring, you can rename `log4j.xml` into `log4j-myapp.xml` and configure log4j using [Log4jConfigListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html).
2. If you're not using Spring, you could write your own `Log4jConfigListener` inspired by the Spring one.
3. Package your appender in a separate JAR, and place the JAR into server shared libraries.

Comment: all these approaches seems big change in production , so i guess  there  isn't any simple way to avoid the Log4JCustomAppender escape from jetty parent class loader ?

Comment: Using Log4jConfigListener is not that a big change, but if you need a quick fix for production, I don't have any solution.